# How to one-hot encode column with two values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

If I one-hot encode a column with 3 possible values like this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit([0, 1, 2])
lb.classes_
lb.transform([1, 0])
```

Then I get:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

which is exactly what I would like. 3 columns = 1 column for each possible value.

But, if I have 2 possible values like this:

```
lb.fit([0, 1])
lb.classes_
lb.transform([1, 0])
```

I get:

```
array([[1],
       [0]])
```

which is only 1 column, even if I have 2 possible values. What I would like to end up in this case is:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

How can I get the 2 column result in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). For example:

```
In [37]: oh = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

In [38]: oh.fit([[0], [1]])
Out[38]:
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<type 'float'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values=2, sparse=False)

In [39]: oh.transform([[1], [0]])
Out[39]:
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like a solution. But, how do I feed a single column of a Pandas data frame into the fit function? With the LabelBinarizer that is really easy, but the OneHotEncoder doesn't seem to take a Pandas column directly.

Comment: With Pandas you can use `get_dummies`. Eg; `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [0,1,0]})` and `pd.get_dummies(df['a'])`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pandas.get_dummies is the easiest solution in my case:

```
pd.get_dummies([1, 0])
```